# Is "This project aims to…" logically correct?

Tags: word-usage

My (engineering) students often start an executive summary with a phrase such as

> This project aims to… [create a system which can…]

I sometimes correct them to write

> The aim of this project is to…

But I don't have good evidence this is any better; I'm worried that it might simply be a stylistic preference. (I prefer only to comment on writing style, where it deserves comment, rather than coerce it to my own.)

My feeling is that a "project" is not an agent — it cannot have aims (nor desires, etc.) of its own. Is there something more concrete I can refer to either back up my reasoning or discount it?

Comment: It depends on how formal you're trying to be.  Since (as you observe) a project isn't sentient it cannot (consciously) "aim" to do anything.  But in less formal writing it's common to anthropomorphize things like projects and treat them as if they were conscious entities.  Probably for your students' uses in a reasonably formal presentation it would be wise to avoid such informality, however.  (I'll let the P-ists come along and quote chapter and verse for you.)

Comment: I'd go beyond what @HotLicks said and say that a project *can* aim. A collective body/being/organism can be sentient and goal-driven. It can even act as an individual. And this is not anthropomorphizing - there are plenty of social and other collective bodies in nature that are sentient and goal-oriented (as a collection). (In fact, individual human beings are each such a collection.)

Comment: Both are fine. See my recent [answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/314662/142322) to a similar question. In this context, the *project* is a metonymic reference to the *people* directing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I sympathize with your feeling but, especially given your expressed preference for only commenting on

> writing style, where it deserves comment, rather than [coercing] it to

conform with yours, I don't think your 'correction' is supportable. While a project cannot have a literal *intention*, it may have an *object* or a *desired outcome*, and so this definition applies:

> **7.** To have (something) as an **object**, intention, or **desired outcome**; to be determined upon; to seek to achieve or obtain.
>
> **a.** *intr.* With infinitive as complement. Also simply: to intend, to mean (formerly chiefly *Eng. regional* and *U.S.*, now *colloq.*).

["aim, v.". OED Online. March 2016. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/4348?rskey=Jt1VLZ&result=4&isAdvanced=false (accessed March 20, 2016). Bold emphasis mine.]

While this (latter) meaning of "to intend, to mean" (part, but not the whole of, meaning 7a) is expressly *colloquial* (thus informal), it may be that the interpretation supported by senses from 1841 and 1903 refers to the general meaning given in the main definition (7), that is, 'aim' is used without a colloquial flavor with reference to an **object** or **desired outcome**:

> ....
>   1841   *Ladies' Repository* Jan. 7/2   The Repository will aim to entertain as well as instruct.
>   ....
>   1903   *McClure's Mag.* July 318/1   Each factory aimed to add barrel works as soon as able.

(op. cit.)

Although these senses are culled from the popular press, they suggest a movement away from purely colloquial use; additionally, the contemporary dictionaries I checked do not stipulate the meaning cited is colloquial in contemporary use.

In 1841, the ladies involved with the Repository may very well have seen their repository as a collective capable of group intention; however, it is unlikely that the factories mentioned in 1903 were regarded as individual or collective human agents capable of having intentions.

---

A quick look at available formal use in contemporary literature supports the claim that 'aims to' is used frequently with subjects that are neither individual nor collective human agents:

> This chapter **aims to** examine engineering students' communication competence ....

([*Handbook of Research on Effective Communication, Leadership, and Conflict Resolution*](https://books.google.com/books?id=FXqmCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA376&dq=%22aims%20to%22%20engineering&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwilheqtgM_LAhVEzGMKHTEzDUAQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22aims%20to%22%20engineering&f=false), Normore, Anthony H. IGI Global, Feb 26, 2016 - Language Arts & Disciplines.)

> The programme **aims to** 'silence' the potential triggers of violent reactions, ....

([*The Psychology of Restorative Justice: Managing the Power Within*](https://books.google.com/books?id=xRugCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT194&dq=%22aims%20to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2hvaT_M7LAhVL3WMKHWZTA_0Q6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22aims%20to%22&f=false), Theo Gavrielides, Routledge, Feb 24, 2016 - Law.)

> Unless your paper **aims to** be striking because of its stylistic novelty, ....

([*A Guide to Professional Doctorates in Business and Management*](https://books.google.com/books?id=GqNiCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT241&dq=%22aims%20to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjU4qH6_c7LAhVB7WMKHab3CBU4ChDoAQgrMAM#v=onepage&q=%22aims%20to%22&f=false), Lisa Anderson, Jeff Gold, Jim Stewart, Richard Thorpe, SAGE, Oct 15, 2015 - Business & Economics.)

Comment: Extremely thorough answer, thank you — I think I'll have to agree with you that my position is not supported by both definition and popular use, although I would like to say that the examples you offer at the end are the type of thing I don't like my own students doing `:)`

Comment: @WillRobertson, welcome. The thoroughness is my attempt to convince myself and overcome my distaste for the use. Being old and crochety I wouldn't accept it despite common formal use, and would insist that sort of circumlocution was unnecessary in any form (that is, no "The aim of this project is" either). For example, in "This chapter *aims to examine*..." the specific verb could be "contains" and the examination might best be "analysis". In short, the use of "aims to" with reference to other than a volitional agent is flawed word choice that should be fixed during editing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that it's a matter of style. In my opinion, I find the first to be more posh. In fact, I'd even go so far as to say it evokes passion; the writer wants the project to be the focus. It's like when projects are given names - the name usually becomes the focus; the creators are proud of their project and treat it like it's a living thing. (Yes, I agree it sounds silly.)

Consider:

> The favourite subject of James is English.

vs.

> James' favourite subject is English.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct, it's a matter of preference and style. While the first definitely personifies the project, it is still very much the same as the second.